# Devise reset password in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to reset a user's password directly in the database. I can see that the passwords are typically stored as an encrypted hash- what are my choices?

I'm using Devise.

Comment: `update user set password=crypt_function('new password here')`?

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed that you said 'directly in the database'. Then the 1st comment you got works best.

If you still could do it through rails (e.g. in a migration) you could try this:

```
user = User.find(...)
# set plain text password, it will run 'encrypted_password=' under the hood
user.password = "new password" 
user.save
```

after that you may want to send email notifications or resetting authentication_token, depending on your case.

Answer (score 1):

@cjm2671, short answer is no and you shouldn't. See how Devise does it in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L4

```
  # Verifies whether an password (ie from sign in) is the user password.
  def valid_password?(password)
    return false if encrypted_password.blank?
    bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password)
    password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt.salt)
    Devise.secure_compare(password, encrypted_password)
  end
```

Why do you want to do it directly on the DB?

If you must, you will need BCrypt on the database (e.g. pgcrypto for PostgreSQL) and the value of `self.class.peper`. I'm assuming `bcrypt.salt` will be provided by BCrypt.

**UPDATE:**

I'm starting to doubt is possible, I jump to quickly to pgcrypto, but it doesn't seem to do what you want.